# F5 and F6 MacBook Pro brightness buttons show on-screen icon but do not change screen brightness

Tags: display, macbook, vmware, macbook-pro

On a 2015 MacBook Pro, the F5 and F6 buttons control the screen brightness. When I press them the on-screen display appears and the brightness level bars move up and down in response to my keyed inputs, however the actual screen brightness doesn't change.

If I go to system preferences > Displays > Brightness, and adjust there, the screen brightness changes as expected.

This machine also runs VMWare for Windows, in case that's relevant.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're hitting the wrong buttons.

F5 and F6 are the keyboard backlight brightness buttons.

F1 and F2 are the screen brightness buttons.

At least that's true on my US QWERTY 2013 15" rMBP. I'll bet your 2015 model is the same.

Comment: It's amazing that I got as far as putting the question here on StackExchange without realising that! You are of course correct ;) I'd manage to convince myself that previously these same keys did work, and now didn't.